# What's the meaning of "daylight" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Below is a briefs of the Secretary of State, Pompeo in NYC recently and I really have no idea what this means.

> (Pompeo)
>   What I can say is this. I have been in the Secretary of State now for 30 odd days. I think there is no ***daylight*** between the South Koreans the Japanese and the United States with respect to our approach to how we resolve this issue with respect to North Korea. I've spoken to my counterparts there. I've spoken to a Mr. Moon there. We understand their concerns. We understand the risks that could be posed to them and an agreement that we reach will provide an outcome that each of those countries can sign on to as well.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, not all online dictionaries out there have this definition listed in their entries for *daylight*. *The English Oxford Living Dictionaries* does, however. See [**definition 1.2**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/daylight):

> 1.2 An appreciable distance or difference between one person or thing and another.
>
> *‘their views on education are so close that it's difficult to see daylight between them’*
>
> *‘the growing daylight between himself and the leading jockey’*

So, what your sentence is saying is that there is no significant difference or disagreement between all these countries with respect to how they're going to handle that issue they have with North Korea.